# Vuejs: v-model array in multiple input

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I have an input text field with a v-model attached, and every time someone hits the "Add" button, another input text gets added to the DOM with the same v-model attached. I thought I'd then get an array of the v-model values, but it only gets the value of the first v-model input:

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="references">
    <input v-model="references" type="text">
  </div>
  <button @click="addReference">Add</button>
</div>
```

The html I append to the dom is triggered by the `addReference` method:

```
addReference: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.references);
  var inputEl = '<input v-model="references" type="text">';
  $('#references').append(inputEl);
}
```

Is this something Vue.js can't do? Is there a different approach of gathering values from dynamic dom elements with Vue.js?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    references: "text"
  },
  methods: {
    addReference: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(this.references);
      var inputEl = '<input v-model="references" type="text">';
      $('#references').append(inputEl);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="references">
    <input v-model="references" type="text">
  </div>
  <button @click="addReference">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking back after using Vue for a couple years, at this personal "hello world" Vue question makes me smile, come a long way :D Thanks againd @Bill Criswell

Comment: I love to hear that! Sorry I didn't see this sooner.

Comment: No problem ^^ Vue makes it so easy to do quite complex things, absolutely loving it still

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You're thinking through DOM, it's a hard as hell habit to break. Vue recommends you approach it data first.

It's kind of hard to tell in your exact situation but I'd probably use a `v-for` and make an array of `finds` to push to as I need more.

Here's how I'd set up my instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    finds: []
  },
  methods: {
    addFind: function () {
      this.finds.push({ value: '' });
    }
  }
});
```

And here's how I'd set up my template:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Finds</h1>
  <div v-for="(find, index) in finds">
    <input v-model="find.value" :key="index">
  </div>
  <button @click="addFind">
    New Find
  </button>
</div>
```

Although, I'd try to use something besides an `index` for the `key`.

Here's a demo of the above: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/24txy506/9/

Comment: Aha! So by making finds an array, which allows you to create a v-for, you kind of tell vue it's going to be an array, opposed to expecting v-model single-value to array-value magic of vuejs! Thanks a bunch! Absolutely loving Vuejs.

Comment: Actually @Bill Criswell, although this has cleared up some things, it's not really an answer to what I need, so let me try to rephrase. I have an array of  references to a find, and when someone adds a find (clicks the + button) a new input field appears that can be filled with another reference. So basically it's a list of references that a user can provide.

Comment: That's what the fiddle is doing as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `thinking too DOM, it's a hard as hell habit to break`

Comment: How did vuejs knew that It should access the find[x].value? even without specifying the x?...

Comment: When I try this, I get `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1737 TypeError: Cannot read property '_withTask' of undefined`

Comment: It's possible to use Array type with no key? Like something `["aa", "bb"]`, or Vue need an Array of objects?

Comment: You can but you'd need to use an `index` as the `:key`. I just noticed in this  answer I don't use a `key` so I'll update that.

Comment: It's working but not reflecting in a computed property @BillCriswell

Answer (score 31):

If you were asking how to do it in vue2 and make options to insert and delete it, please, have a look an [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Eugene82/mjnyLm0q/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    finds: [] 
  },
  methods: {
    addFind: function () {
      this.finds.push({ value: 'def' });
    },
    deleteFind: function (index) {
      console.log(index);
      console.log(this.finds);
      this.finds.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Finds</h1>
  <div v-for="(find, index) in finds">
    <input v-model="find.value">
    <button @click="deleteFind(index)">
      delete
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <button @click="addFind">
    New Find
  </button>
  
  <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

Here's a demo of the above:https://jsfiddle.net/sajadweb/mjnyLm0q/11

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: [{ name: 'sajadweb',email:'sajadweb@outlook.com' }] 
  },
  methods: {
    addUser: function () {
      this.users.push({ name: '',email:'' });
    },
    deleteUser: function (index) {
      console.log(index);
      console.log(this.finds);
      this.users.splice(index, 1);
      if(index===0)
      this.addUser()
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Add user</h1>
  <div v-for="(user, index) in users">
    <input v-model="user.name">
    <input v-model="user.email">
    <button @click="deleteUser(index)">
      delete
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <button @click="addUser">
    New User
  </button>
  
  <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
</div>
```