# Vuejs problem ; How to bind new elements added to DOM?

Tags: vue.js, binding

I Want to add new element to the DOM after new Vue instance created.
I know I can re initiate the instance of vue but it seems it is not good idea because vue have to re render all elements again. So is there a method to bind just new element to the data scope?

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <span>{{ a }}<span>

    <div id="newElem"></div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var mainApp = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                "a": "aa",
                "b": "bb"    
            }
        });

        $("#newElem").html("<span>{{ b }}</span>")

    });

</script>
```

This code renders {{ b }} unbinded. I am looking for a method for preventing this.

Thanks

Comment: Problem was shown in this demo app : https://jsfiddle.net/mirshahreza/y3hb790a/5/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

`<div v-html="newElem"></div>`

`el: "#app",
    data: {
        "a": "aa",
        "b": "bb"

    },
    created() {
        this.newElem = "<span>{{ b }}</span>";
    }`

Comment: I want to add element at run time so it is not exist at develop time

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell your ultimate goal here but I'll take a shot.

Ideally, you wouldn't touch the DOM, you'd want to update the data and let Vue handle the DOM for you.

I think you want to initialize `b` as `undefined` and set that when you're ready for it to be displayed.

```
data: {
  a: 'aa',
  b: undefined,
}
```

Then in your template you can have something like this:

```
<span v-if="b">{{ b }}</span>
```

This way the span won't display until `b` is truthy.

Then, later, when `b` is ready, you would `mainApp.b = 'bb'`.

Here's a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/crswll/vtu8nzea/1/

If you make add a more complete use case I can likely help further.

Also, this answer might help as well. It's kind of like the next level of this thinking: [Vuejs: v-model array in multiple input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825065/vuejs-v-model-array-in-multiple-input/34828165#34828165)

Comment: My problem is not with data. it is about dynamic DOM. I am developing a software that have a run time designer so i have to handle run time elements that binds to current data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my case is the situation that element is not present at first and it will add to the document dynamically. a jsfiddle shows you the exact condition : https://jsfiddle.net/mirshahreza/y3hb790a/5/